# Antlr4 how to build API for a grammar

Tags: java, parsing, antlr4

I have a simple grammar like the *hello* (from the antlr website) and then the autogenerated java code.
In the end, to test the grammar I add the following:

```
public static void main( String[] args) throws Exception 
  {
    HelloLexer lexer = new HelloLexer( new ANTLRInputStream("hello world"));
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream( lexer );
    HelloParser parser = new HelloParser( tokens );
    ParseTree tree = parser.r();
    System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser));
  }
```

and everything is fine.

As we can see, the input is made of strings like "*hello world*" , but **my goal is to provide API for a certain grammar**. So, I'd like to know if there is a way to provide the input by java classes, for example instead of write "hello world", I want to put a java class like MyGrammarExpression that is composed by components of the grammar (like OWLExpression in OWLAPI) and then normally parsed.
Does ANTLR4 provide a way for that? Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you asking how you can load text from a file to feed it to your parser? There is the ANTLRFileStream class for that, but really, how to open an input stream in Java with the content of a file is most basic programming knowledge. Or is your question about something else?

Comment: Well it is a question about something else. Since I need to provide API for a grammar, I want to structure each component of the grammar in order to allow the final user the use classes. Exactly what happens in OWLAPI.